# Pandas: locate entries based on multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Label': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    'Col_1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'],
    'Col_2': ['12', '15', '24', '24', '24', '19', '19', '29'],
    'Col_3': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'R']
})
print(df)
   Label Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
0      1     A    12     X
1      0     A    15     Y
2      0     B    24     Z
3      0     B    24     Z
4      1     B    24     T
5      1     C    19     Q
6      1     C    19     Q
7      0     D    29     R
```

I want to filter for the entries where `Col_1` and `Col_2` are the same, but `Label` and `Col_3` are different. So that I can look at if `Col_3` had effect on the `Label`.

In short, I want to obtain the following data. I can see `Label` is changed when `Col_3` is changed.

```py
   Label Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
3      0     B    24     Z
4      1     B    24     T
```

My attempt is to have an iterative approach. First I take out the unique "pairs" (first value from `Col_` and second value from `Col_2`. Then I iterate over the dataframe and search for above mentioned situation. Certainly, this is not the most efficient approach.

```py
pairs = list(df.apply(lambda x: (x['Col_1'], x['Col_2']), axis=1).unique())
print(pairs)
# [('A', '12'), ('A', '15'), ('B', '24'), ('C', '19'), ('D', '29')]

for col_1, col_2 in pairs:
    search_data = df[(df['Col_1'] == col_1) & (df['Col_2'] == col_2)]
    if len(search_data) > 1 and len(search_data['Label'].unique()) > 1 and len(search_data['Col_3'].unique()) > 1:
        print(search_data)

   Label Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
2      0     B    24     Z
3      0     B    24     Z
4      1     B    24     T
```

How can I perform this operation in vectorized fashion?

I feel like it should start with this, but how can I add additional filtering?

```py
df[df[['Col_1', 'Col_2']].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to filter for where "Col_1 and Col_2 are the same, but Label and Col_3 are different". How do you do this? Col_1 are letters, Col_2 are numbers, they should never be the same. Oh never mind, you're asking for a row-by-row difference, not a column-over-column difference.

Comment: I'd like to consider them as "pairs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try chaining what you start with `duplicated`, with a `drop_duplicates` to remove a row B and C that are actually fully duplicates, then `groupby` col_1 and col_2 and `filter` where the `size` is more than 1 to keep all the wanted rows with B because the row with C is alone

```
print(
    df.loc[df[['Col_1', 'Col_2']].duplicated(keep=False)]
      .drop_duplicates()
      .groupby(['Col_1', 'Col_2'])
      .filter(lambda x: x['Label'].size>1)
)
   Label Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
2      0     B    24     Z
4      1     B    24     T
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It almost solves my problem, except I had to use `.filter(lambda x: len(x['Label'].unique())>1)` because in my original data, I not only obtained your output, but also for ex. two entries both having Label 0, X, 25, but different Col_3 values. With using `.filter(lambda x: len(x['Label'].unique())>1)` I got rid of them, too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IbrahimBerber glad you adapted to fit your real case, and FYI you can use `nunique` like `len(x['Label'].unique())` is the same as `x['Label'].nunique()`